# How to get the values of text boxes which are dynamically created in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to design the multiple text boxes based on user clicks shown in below image

[design of my html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZsJG.png)

But whenever i click on + button value in text box is repeating my html is code like below

```html
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: -10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-10" *ngFor="let rowplus of rowplus" style="margin-top: 12px;">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Command" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="cli.cmd[rowplus[0]]"  name="cmd" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top: 12px;">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addrow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="subrow()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to avoid this and how to use dynamic value for [(ngmodel)] .

Comment: Just *don't* bind them all to the same thing? Could you give a little context?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same variable for all text boxes

```
[(ngModel)]="cli.cmd"
```

You can either use `index`

```
<div class="col-lg-10" *ngFor="let rowplus of rowplus; let idx=index" style="margin-top: 12px;">
  <input  type="text" id="command" placeholder="Command" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="cli[idx].cmd" name="cmd" />
</div>
```

or store the value in the `*ngFor` interator variable `rowplus`

```
<div class="col-lg-10" *ngFor="let rowplus of rowplus" style="margin-top: 12px;">
  <input  type="text" id="command" placeholder="Command" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="rowplus.cmd" name="cmd" />
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working im getting error when im using index zone.js:346 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/cli/cli.component.html:29:105 caused by: Cannot read property 'cmd' of undefined(…) ................                                    rowplus is an array it is just having some dummy values for every add button click im pushing some dummy values into rowplus to give me the new row .

Comment: Then `cli` is probably not an array, or if it is an array it. Please add more details about what you try to accomplish.

Comment: cli is object of class                                                                               "class CLI {
  constructor(
    public name:string,
    public addr: string,
    public password: string,
    public cmd: string[],
    public reason: string
      ) {  }
}"                                                                                                                                   with in component class  im declaring cli object like below                                 "cli = new CLI('', '', '', [],'');"

Comment: These are  complete form elements in which i have one dynamically created text box id=command mentioned above

Comment: "These are complete form elements in which i have one dynamically created text box id=command mentioned above". Somehow this doesn't help me to understand what you try to accomplish. Please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: are u able to get it now ?

Comment: `let idx="index"` is not how I showed it in my answer and I don't think this is working. I wonder why you don'g get an error for this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of your data structure. I just can say that if you want to set `cli[idx].cmd` you need to ensure it exists so it doesn't reference undefined.